# sparql count not existing properties as zero

Tags: sparql, rdf

Here is my query:

```
PREFIX     :  <http://example.org/ns#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT  ?id ?name (count(?s) as ?count)
WHERE {
   ?t  a        :Tag ;
       :hasId   ?id ;
       :hasName ?name 
  OPTIONAL { ?s    :hasTag  ?t ;
                rdf:type    ?type  }
  FILTER (?type in (:Client, :Project, :Staff))
} GROUP BY ?id ?name
```

Tags with no objects are not included in the result. How can I get them also without using union?
Performance is also important

The goal is to gather information about tags (id, name) and number of objects they assign to (if no such objects count must be 0). Tag data sample:

```
:tag912 :hasId        "912"^^xsd:integer
:tag912 :hasName      "Phones"
```

This tag is assigned to 6 objects.

This query works for me:

```
PREFIX  :     <http://example.org/ns#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT  ?id ?name ?count
WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?id ?name (count(?s) as ?count)
    WHERE {
       ?t    a       :Tag ;
             :hasId   ?id ;
             :hasName ?name .
       ?s    :hasTag  ?t ;
          rdf:type    ?type 
      FILTER (?type in (:Client, :Project, :Staff))
    } GROUP BY ?id ?name
  } UNION {
    SELECT ?id ?name (0 as ?count)
    WHERE {
      ?t a        :Tag ;
         :hasId   ?id ;
         :hasName ?name
      FILTER not exists { ?s :hasTag ?t }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I use bindings here? Will it improve performance?
Thank you

Comment: It would be nice if you provide more information, among others, the goal of the query, sample data, etc.

Comment: And you want to have the number of objects that do not have a tag? Do you know how to get just the number of tags that do not have a tag? With your query I don't see a way to avoid union or sub-select as you're grouping by tag Id and tag name, so what should be the id resp. name that denotes untagged objects? BIND + IF-ELSE could be an option to bind a tag "untagged" to those objects that do not have a tag

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added more details to the question. How can I use BIND + IF-ELSE here? As I think it must be faster than union

Answer (score 1):

Why *not* use `UNION`?

Aside from that, your query is focused on `?t` tags and their `?id` and `?name` — so it's not surprising that results don't include `?s` objects which lack `?t` and hence lack any `?id` and `?name`…

I think this may get you going in the right direction —

```
PREFIX     :  <http://example.org/ns#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT  ?id 
        ?name 
        (count(?s) as ?count)
WHERE 
  {            ?s    rdf:type    ?type  
               FILTER ( ?type IN ( :Client, :Project, :Staff ) ) .
    OPTIONAL { ?s  :hasTag   ?t    .
               ?t  rdf:type  :Tag  ;
                   :hasId    ?id   ;
                   :hasName  ?name }
  } 
GROUP BY ?id ?name
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this does not work for me either. I think actually it's the same query as I posted in the beginning of the question

Comment: My query is not the same as your original.  But the updates to your question changed your stated objective (from "how many objects have no tag?" to "how many objects does each tag apply to?"), and make my modified query irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if ?s is bound in your filter:

```
PREFIX     :  <http://example.org/ns#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT  ?id ?name (COUNT(?s) as ?count)
WHERE {
  ?t   a        :Tag ;
       :hasId   ?id ;
       :hasName ?name .
  OPTIONAL {
    ?s    :hasTag  ?t ;
          rdf:type    ?type .
  }
  FILTER (!BOUND(?s) || ?type in (:Client, :Project, :Staff))
} GROUP BY ?id ?name
```

I don't know if this is faster than a union (or a bunch of unions), however.

Comment: I have not so much data but for 1000 tags and 20000 objects I get

Comment: 289 ms for your query